# Django Rest Framework, ModelSerializers and custom fields validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using latest version of Django and DRF.

I have a rather complex requirement I can't find a solution for. I'll try to simplify it.

Let's say I have a model that has two fields. `field_a` and `field_b`

I have a `ModelSerializer` for it. I `POST` a request with its fields. The fields get validated with the model and then against my two serializer functions `validate_field_a` and `validate_field_b`. All is well.

Now I'd like my `POST` request to include a third field that is not a member of that model. let's call it `field_c`. I have a custom `def create(self, validated_data):` in my serializer which saves everything to the database.

with regards to `field_c` I would like to:

1. Custom Validate it. just like I do with the other two fields.
2. Require that it is mandatory for the whole request to succeed and if it's not, issue a "Field is required" error just like if I forgot to POST one of my required model fields.
3. Have the chance to take `field_c` and save it onto a totally different unrelated Model's row in the db.

I can't seem to get around that. If I add `field_c` to the `fields` meta - it throws an exception saying justifiably that `field_c` is not in my model. If I don't include it in fields, the `validate_field_c` which I really want to put there doesn't even get called.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the custom field in your serializer as a `write_only` field and override the create method so that you can handle the custom field's value.

Something like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_c = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c')

    def validate_field_c(self, value):
        if value is 'test':
            raise ValidationError('Invalid')
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        field_c = validated_data.pop('field_c')

        return MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use ModelSerializer for this - use a serializer that recreates the same fields as your model & include `field_c` as you would.

I understand that you want your model to do some of the work in the validation process but the design of DRF is such that it isolates these responsibilities. You can read more about it [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework). Basically, the serializer should be the one doing all the validation heavy-lifting.

Of course, this means that you'll have to explicitly define the validation methods in the serializer.

In your custom `create()` method you can create the model instance or do whatever you want in it as required.

Comment: This creates duplicated validation rules in the model and the serializer. Better to keep the validation in the model, continue inheriting from ModelSerializer, and customize validation by overriding run_validation() if absolutely necessary e.g. adjust self.fields['field_name'].validators.